Question for Vaishnavas only - Faith of non-believers in Shri Hari? Is there no punishment at all?
For if it were so then there is no reward or incitement if we all get moksha or there is no justice. Question for Vaishnavas only - faith of non-believers in Shri Hari? Is there any punishment? Is God lacking that much importance?
In most religions, there’s some sort of punishment for insulting God or vilifying the Scriptures.

@skathanks for that, but if we Hindus can't even have these discussions then no wonder people do not value our dharma if we don't even have guts to talk or ask questions. this does not call for hate, just like anything else in the world, if people hate cuz of it, too bad and may Bhagwan guide them.

Not all non-believers are considered the same.
For example, Bhagawan Krishna says in Bhagavad Gita -

अथ चैनं नित्यजातं नित्यं वा मन्यसे मृतम्।
तथापि त्वं महाबाहो नैवं शोचितुमर्हसि।।2.26।।


But even if thou think of the Atman as being constantly born and constantly dying, even then, O mighty-armed, thou shouldst not grieve.

Here, the important thing that Bhagawan focuses on is not the belief in a permanent Atman, but in the removal of grief. Thus, even an atheist or someone who does not believe in a permanent Atman, should focus on removal of suffering.
Now, mere atheism (of any form) is not sufficient to qualify a person for punishment. (This also applies to the specific atheism defined as lack of belief in Bhagawan Vishnu).
Bhagavad Gita describes those kind of atheists that receive punishment-

16.7 Neither do the demoniacal persons under-stand what is to be done and what is not to be done; nor does purity, or even good conduct or truthfulness exist in them.


16.8 They say that the world is unreal, it has no basis, it is without a God. It is born of mutual union brought about by passion! What other (cause can there be)?


16.9 Holding on to this view, (these people) who are of depraved character, of poor intellect, given to fearful actions and harmful, wax strong for the ruin of the world.


16.10 Giving themselves up to insatiable passion, filled with vanity, pride and arrogance, adopting bad abjectives due to delusion, and having impure resolves, they engage in actions.


16.11 Beset with innumerable cares which end (only) with death, holding that the enjoyment of desirable objects is the highest goal, feeling sure that this is all.


16.12 Bound by hundreds of shackles in the form of hope, giving themselves wholly to passion and anger, they endeavour to amass wealth through foul means for the enjoyment of desirable objects.


16.13 'This has been gained by me today; I shall acquire this desired object. This is in hand; again, this wealth also will come to me.'


16.14 'That enemy has been killed by me, and I shall kill others as well. I am the lord, I am the enjoyer, I am well-established, mighty and happy.'


16.15 'I am rich and high-born; who else is there similar to me? I shall perform sacrifices; I shall give, I shall rejoice,'-thus they are diversely deluded by non-discrimination.


16.16 Bewildered by numerous thoughts, caught in the net of delusion, (and) engrossed in the enjoyment of desirable objects, they fall into a foul hell.


16.17 Self-conceited, haughty, filled with pride and intoxication of wealth, they perform sacrifices which are so in name only, with ostentation and regardless of the injunctions.


16.18 Depending on their egoism, power and pride, and also of desire and wrath, these malicious men hate Me in their own bodies and in those of others.


16.19 I cast for ever those hateful, cruel, evil-doers in the worlds, the vilest of human beings, verily into the demoniacal classes.

Really, its a big list of criteria that an atheist must also satisfy in order to be punished.

Punishing other souls simply because they do not adhere to one's own way of worship is not a tenet of Sanatana Dharma.
However, a blasphemer is liable for punishment as per Vedic law. He may be a blasphemer of Lord Shiva, Vishnu, a spiritual master, or any other Deity as ordained in the Vedas. An example is Daksha Prajapati who offended Lord Shiva and was duly punished.

कर्णौ पिधाय निरयाद्यदकल्प ईशे धर्मावितर्यसृणिभिर्नृभिरस्यमाने ।

Satī continued: If one hears an irresponsible person blaspheme the
master and controller of religion, one should block his ears and go
away if unable to punish him (SB 4.4.17).

Lord Krishna has clearly stated that everyone follows His path in all ways, and He rewards them accordingly.

ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम् । मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते
मनुष्याः पार्थ सर्वशः ॥ ११ ॥

As all surrender unto Me, I reward them accordingly. Everyone follows
My path in all respects, O son of Pṛthā (Bhagavad Gita 4.11).


Ekam Sat Vipraah bahudha vadanti
The One absolute truth is described in many ways by the wise beings (Rg Veda
1.164.46).


It seems like some sectarian quotes from Puranas support some kind of punishments.

Avaishnava Brahmana is equal to outcastes as per Vaishnava Puranas:


From Padma Purana VI.224
51-53. A brāhmaṇa should not mark his body with any other symbol than that of
Viṣṇu—with other symbols than the conch, disc, mace, sword and the
Śārṅga (bow) of Viṣṇu. He should burn his body with marks (made with
Viṣṇu’s symbols). He, whose body is burnt with (i.e. has) other marks,
is not entitled to (performing) rites. One should avoid a brāhmaṇa not
having the disc (-mark) from a distance. In the world one should not
look at a brāhmaṇa who is not a devotee of Viṣṇu as (one does not look
at) a cāṇḍāla. Viṣṇu’s devotee, even if he is outside the castes,
purifies the three worlds.


Wearing Tripuranda is a practice prescribed for low castes as per
vaishnava puranas:


From Padma Purana VI.225
19-20. O goddess, if a brāhmaṇa, learned and born in a noble family has put
on (the mark of) sacred ash, one should avoid such a brāhmaṇa, as a
pot in which liquor is left as the remnant. The mark of three lines is
the practice for those who are śūdras and like śūdras. There is no
doubt that a brāhmaṇa having the mark of three lines, falls.


All Non-Vaishnavas are heretics:


From Padma Purana VI.234.26
A devotee of Viṣṇu should not see, talk with or touch a heretic, one
doing a prohibited act, a fallen person or a cāṇḍāla. A brāhmaṇa who
is not devoted to Viṣṇu is called a heretic.
From Padma Purana VI.235.
2c-5 - Those who, deluded by ignorance, describe any other deity as
being superior to Viṣṇu, the lord of the world, are said to be
heretics. Those who use skulls, apply ash, use bones, have non-Vedic
marks, have matted hair and bark-garments though they do not belong to
the hermit-stage of life are (said to be) heretics. Those brāhmaṇas
who are without such marks dear to Viṣṇu as conches, discs,
ūrdhvapuṇḍra (upright sectarian marks on the forehead) are said to be
heretics.


This answer belongs in the hall-of-fame of HSE.  What an astounding distillation of the essence of Hinduism. @cracklingcyclone

@SK Jokes apart, such level of sectarianism isn't new or unheard of in Hinduism. Around the 1800s, Christian missionary William Ward records of incidents of bloodshed happening in fights between Ramanandi & Naga akharas at Kumbh Mela in Haridwar over rights to take the first bath. Denying the existence of the problem isn't a solution.

you have been here for 3 years @অনু .  Why do you think this post had to be made on meta?  https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/please-stay-away-from-shiva-vs-vishnu-debate  But it never stops, even in 2024.

The questioner found some anti-Siva quotations from Padma Purana - but the same Purana says Siva is Brahman and glorifies sacred ash:
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365420.html

Chapter 108 - How to Prepare Sacred Ash


Śrī Rāma said:

O illustrious one, tell about the origin of the sacred ash, the greatness of the sacred ash, and the religious merit (earned) through the application of the sacred ash.



Śambhu said:
2-8a. O Rāma, I shall tell you about the origin of the sacred ash. (I shall tell you about its effect) by (just) remembering or telling about it. O king, listen to it. He who is that eternal god Sadāśiva, who is saluted by Brahmā, who has three eyes, who is the prop of virtues, who is beyond qualities, who is unchangeable and immutable, had once a desire to create on seeing the three qualities in himself—this triad of qualities should be known as the three Vedas. O dear one, having divided himself and the region there, he created on his right side the son, viz. Brahmā and Hari from his left side. At the back side he created Maheśāna (i.e. Śiva); thus the mighty one created three sons. As soon as they were born they became the three gods—Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Śiva. They distinctly spoke these words: “Who are you? Who are we?” To those sons Śiva said: “You are the sons, (and) I am your father. O sons, resort to these three qualities which are the cause of (all) acts.”

Which scripture says you don't need Vishnu to reach moksha?  The Bhagavad Gita:
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/12/verse/3-4

ये त्वक्षरमनिर्देश्यमव्यक्तं पर्युपासते |
सर्वत्रगमचिन्त्यञ्च कूटस्थमचलन्ध्रुवम् || 3||
सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धय: |
ते प्राप्नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रता: || 4||


ye tv akṣharam anirdeśhyam avyaktaṁ paryupāsate
sarvatra-gam achintyañcha kūṭa-stham achalandhruvam
sanniyamyendriya-grāmaṁ sarvatra sama-buddhayaḥ
te prāpnuvanti mām eva sarva-bhūta-hite ratāḥ


BG 12.3-4: But those who worship the formless aspect of the Absolute Truth—the imperishable, the indefinable, the unmanifest, the all-pervading, the unthinkable, the unchanging, the eternal, and the immoveable—by restraining their senses and being even-minded everywhere, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all beings, also attain Me.

you could argue that the "Me" or Krishna is Vishnu - but only Arjuna and Sanjaya call the preacher of the Gita as Vishnu - whoever spoke the Gita didn't relate himself to the Vishnuist Pantheon in any way.  "Among the Adityas, I am Vishnu" is just a metaphor for "best of breed".

"whoever spoke the Gita didn't relate himself to the Vishnuist Pantheon in any way." -----  Gita 7.19 At the end of many births the man of Knowledge attains Me, (realizing) that Vasudeva is all. Such a high-souled one is very rare.
